# If a sequence of nonnegative continuous functions $(f_n)$ satisfies MCT, does the pointwise limit exist everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuous nonnegative-valued functions on the real line such that
$f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and

\begin{equation}
\sup_{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n(x) dx < \infty.
\end{equation}

Then, it is clear by monotone convergence theorem that the pointwise limit $f(x)$ exists as a finite value almost everywhere. Moreover, the above supremum is the integral of $f(x)$.

However, is it also possible to say that $f(x)$ is finite 'everywhere' or even $f$ is continuous?

I wonder what influence the assumption of $f_n$'s being continuous has. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem check this

Comment: The only thing that restrains you is the eventual infinite limit of $f$ in one point$

Comment: I do not assume any a priori continuity on $f$. In fact that is what I would like to know. What do you mean by 'one point'?

Comment: I answered, if you want details don't hesitate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment,If you have $\forall x, \, \lim_\infty f_n(x) < \infty$, you have a uniform convergence on each segment which implies the continuity of $f$. This is given by Dini's theorem.

However, if you consider $f_0 = 0$ and $f_{n+1}(x) = f_{n}(x) + n \cdot c(x/n^3)$ where $c$ is the hat function that is zero everywhere but on $[-1,1]$ and for $-1 < x \leq 0$ we have $c(x) = x+1$ and for  $0<x <1$, $c(x) = 1-x$, you have
your initial condition respected, but $f_n(0) \to \infty$

But the points where $f(x) = \infty$ are countable, and everywhere else, $f$ is continuous

Comment: What do you mean by everywhere else? How do I know continuity of $f$? Could you explain more?

Comment: Ok so let us define $D = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \, | \, f_n(x) \to \infty\}$. $D$ is countable and $f$ which is defined as the limit of the $f_n$ is defined on $\mathbb{R} \setminus D$ which is open. On each segment included in this set (so locally) by Dini, you have $f$ continuous (and uniform convergence) hence $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus D$.